What $3 \times 3$ matrix gives the determinant $a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}$?
The $2D$ rotation matrix is given by a $2\times{2}$ matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a & -b\\
b & a
\end{bmatrix}$$
The determinant of this matrix is $a^{2}+b^{2}$. Can one construct a $3\times{3}$ matrix for $3D$ rotations where the determinant of the matrix is $a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}$, and the elements of the matrix are $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$. If there is not, is there a $3\times{3}$ or $2\times{2}$ matrix that can be constructed with the same determinant, $a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}$ given complex numbers?

The $2\times 2$ matrix is a rotation matrix iff $a^2+b^2=1.$ As written, it is a rotation and scaling.

Hi! It's usually "determinant"; I don't think I've ever seen "determinate" in any similar context (or at all). Also, if all of the terms must be $\pm a, \pm b, \pm c$, the determinant must be made up of terms of degree $3$, mustn't it? ¶ I just approved an edit to correct the term.

There are $4\times 4$ ones by writing quaternions as matrices. I doubt there are $3\times 3$ ones, because there is no real division algebra of dimension $3$.

What if we are allowed 0s and 1s as well... is it then possible?

$a^2+b^2+c^2 = (a^2+b^2)(\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+ic}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}})(\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-ic}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}})$ And a matrix's determinant is the product of its eigen values. A matrix's determinant is preserved if its multiple by a matrix having determinant=1. So you can construct a great many matrices with that determinant.

Real Entries: 3D Rotation Matrix
In three-dimensional space, rotation matrices are orthogonal ($\mathbf{R}^T\mathbf{R} = \mathbf{I}$) and have a determinant of $1$, reflecting volume preservation during rotation. It's not possible to construct a $3\times3$ rotation matrix with real entries $a, b, c$ where the determinant is $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$, because rotation matrices specifically have determinants of $1$, not a variable sum of squares.
Complex Entries: Constructing a Matrix
For complex entries, consider matrices where we aim for a determinant that reflects the sum of squares of the moduli of complex numbers. Direct construction with a determinant exactly as $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ using straightforward $2\times2$ or $3\times3$ matrices with complex numbers is complex due to the determinant representing volume scaling, not a direct sum of element squares.
Example with Complex Numbers
However, we can consider a $2\times2$ matrix that uses complex entries imaginatively to hint at the sum of squares relation:
$$\begin{bmatrix} a+bi & -c \\ c & a-bi \end{bmatrix}$$
Determinant calculation gives us:
$$\text{det} = (a+bi)(a-bi) - (-c)(c) = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$$
This matrix doesn't serve as a rotation matrix in the real 3D space but illustrates how complex numbers can be used to achieve a specific determinant structure.

In real 3D space, rotation matrices always have a determinant of $1$, not variable sums of squares.
With complex numbers, a $2\times2$ matrix can be constructed to have a determinant of $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$, illustrating the flexibility complex numbers offer in matrix construction, though not representing real-space rotations.


Awesome, thank you!

you can use $2\times 2$ complex matrices to represent $\Bbb R^3$-rotations, as $\text{SO}(3)\cong\text{SU}(2)/\Bbb Z_2$
